# How do I securely format a Buffalo NAS wirelessly?

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, format, shred

I have a Link Station Duo NAS which is attached to a router, how do I securely erase the information on it? File Shredder and Kill disk require it to be attached to my computer which it isn't. I also don't have any other external HDD cases in which I could put the drives and then attach it to my computer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open the case and take the HDD out? You could buy an e-data PCI card.

Answer (score 0):

Another user had a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/32083).

The easiest answer is to remove the drives and format them on a another computer.

I do not see a way to guarantee the data scrubbing remotely with this unit remotely.